# HTTP POST receiving more than one HTTP Response

Tags: asp.net, http, http-post

I have an http POST being actioned via a .NET System.Net.WebRequest as follows:

```
                ...                
                XXXUtilities.Log.WriteLog(string.Format("XXXHTTPPost PostToUri has uri={0}, body={1}", uri, messageBodyAsString));
                System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);

                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.Method = "POST";

                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageBodyAsString);
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                os.Close();

                try
                {
                    using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
                    {
                        if (resp == null) return null;
                        System.IO.StreamReader sr =
                              new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

                        string rs = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();

                        sr.Close();
                        resp.Close();

                        XXXUtilities.Log.WriteLog(string.Format("XXXHTTPPost PostToUri has string response = {0}", rs));

                        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument doc2 = new BsonDocument();

                        doc2.Add("Response", rs);

                        return doc2;
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException e)
                {...
```

This all works fine most of the time.   However, looking at the log files that this creates I spotted something strange.  The suspect log entries look like this:

```
18:59:17.0608 HPSHTTPPost PostToUri has uri=https://salesforce.ringlead.com/cgi-bin/2848/3/dedup.pl, body=LastName=Doe&FirstName=Jon
18:59:17.5608 HPSHTTPPost PostToUri has string response = Success
18:59:18.0295 HPSHTTPPost PostToUri has string response = Success
```

It seems that the Http Response is being received twice.  Is this even technically possible?  i.e. is it possible for an Http POST to receive two Responses, one after the other?  If so, is my code below then liable to be called twice, thus resulting in the observed log file entries?  Many thanks.

Edit:
In response to the comment that the logging code may be broken, here is the logging code:

```
    public class Log
    {
        public static void WriteLog(string commandText)
        {
            string clientDBName = "test";
            string username = "test";
            try
            {

                string filePath = "c:\\Data\\XXXLogs\\" + clientDBName + "logs\\";

                string filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_") + username + ".log";

                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
                if (!dir.Exists)
                {
                    dir.Create();
                }
                System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(
                    filePath + filename
                    , System.IO.FileMode.Append); // Will create if not already exists
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

                writer.WriteLine(); // Writes a line terminator, thus separating entries by 1 blank line
                writer.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff") + " " + commandText);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch { }

        }
    }
```

Comment: No, HTTP returns one response per request. Either this is not the code that runs, or your logging library is broken.

Comment: Well yes, that logging code is broken. It doesn't handle threading and other issues. When the log file is not available for appending, it'll simply run into the empty `catch { }` block and not log the requested line. Use an existing logging library instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I understand that the logging code is broken, but it is logging a very simple sequence at the moment, and the Response is appearing twice, so I don't think the broken logging is actually causing the issue.  It's not as if I'm missing entries - I'm seeing too many!!  Thank you.

Comment: You _are_ missing an entry: the second request (_"PostToUri has uri"_) is missing.